# SharePoint 2013 - Build a Publishing page that has a view for documents

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Within SharePoint 2013, is there an OOTB way to drop a view onto a publishing page that lists documents, in which the columns can be sorted by date created, name, etc...?

I am assuming I need to create a new document library that has all my PDFs.  I would then reference that document library onto my publishing page, with a view of columns for these documents.  Is there an easy way to do this from the UI ribbon?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a List View Web Part to a page and then configure the view to only show specific columns? If that is the case, then you can edit the page, add a List View Web Part, edit the web part properties, and then edit the current view of the web part to display whatever columns you want and configure sorting and filtering of those columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Clk** said it first in comments, so kudos.

You can do this by inserting a list or library Web Part into the page.

**Here is a link to an article that explains the process if you prefer reading :**

http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.co.uk/2008/04/sharepoint-web-part-for-document.html

**Here is a short video of the process for SharePoint 2013** :

*In this video, they add a list, but it is the same process, list, library, calendar, tasks, whatever!*

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PJOqJyYBvJo

**It is fairly similar in SharePoint 2010**.

Here is a video :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O0qRFBR4WhM

it is really easy :)